# "string".downcase! returning nil why?

Tags: ruby

`String#downcase!` returning the downcased string or sometimes nil. Unable to understand why it is behaving differently.

I tried:

```
"something".downcase! # returning nil
"Something".downcase! # returning "something"
```

Comment: It does exactly what is is supposed to do: `Downcases the contents of str, returning nil if no changes were made. Note: case replacement is effective only in ASCII region.` https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-downcase-21

Comment: `"something".downcase!` never returns "something". `"Something".downcase!` does. :)

Comment: Can you please explain which *exact* part of the documentation is unclear to you? That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation so that this question doesn't arise again in the future. Also, it would help answering your question, since otherwise the answer is just "because the documentation says so".

Answer (score 4):

That's because you are using `downcase!` instead of `downcase`. If you take a look at [Ruby's documentation about String class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-downcase), you will see that without the exclamation mark, it will always return a string with downcased characters (as you want), while if you call it with the exclamation mark it will return nil if no changes were made.

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks friend, I changed the answer a lot of times while writing and didn't see that mistake, edited :)